# C++ unexpected calling of function of inherited classes

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I made following 3 classes:

```
struct Parent1
{
    virtual void f()
    {
        cout << "\nParent1::f";
    }
};
struct Parent2
{
    virtual void g()
    {
        cout << "\nParent2::g";
    }
    virtual void z()
    {
        cout << "\nParent2::z";
    }
};
struct Child : public Parent1, public Parent2
{
    virtual void h()
    {
        cout << "\nChild::h";
    }
};
```

In main, when I call function `z` of `Parent2`, it instead calls function `h` of the child class. Why is it happening so?
Following is the `main` function:

```
int main()
{
    Child obj;
    Parent2 * p2 = (Parent2*)(Parent1*)&obj;
    p2->z();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are invoking undefined behavior since you cannot cast from `Parent1*` to `Parent2*`, just get rid of the `(Parent1*)`. (And actually you need neither of the casts, that is done implicitly).

Comment: @n314159 I actually wanted to know the reason why it's happening that way?

Comment: And in fact, in this case I believe `dynamic_cast` will work correctly and do what you want.

Comment: @Paul for a upcast like this, `static_cast` is more than enough (and will even throw a nice error for this kind of mistake! https://ideone.com/cNKWUc)

Comment: @AqleemaSajid it is happening this way because you use unsafe C style cast which does incorrect conversation in this case and does not warn you. And it is one of the main reason why proper C++ cast is recommended to be used instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first explicit conversion from `&obj` i.e. `Child*` to `Parent1*` is an upcast. The result will point to the base class sub-object. The next explicit conversion is from `Parent1*` to `Parent2*`. Since these classes are not directly related, this is a reinterpretation cast. But the types are not pointer-interconvertible, so when you call the function through the reinterpreted pointer, the behaviour of the program is undefined.

You should avoid using C-style casts to prevent mistakes like this. In this case, no explicit cast is needed at all. This works correctly:

```
Parent2 * p2 = &obj;
```

And never reinterpret pointers unless you know what it means and that it is OK to do so.

Comment: You could also mention that `Parent1* p1 = &obj; Parent2* p2 = dynamic_cast<Parent2*>(p1);` will also work, I believe.

Comment: @N.Shead That would also work. Although then it must be mentioned to always check whether dynamic cast returns null or valid pointer.

Comment: Indeed. (Or of course dynamic cast reference types, which will throw.) I just suspect that is more likely what the OP was attempting to do originally, given the multiple inheritance.

Comment: @N.Shead It may be. But OP didn't explain what they are trying to do and why, so we cannot know.